# How do I run a system command in a cydget using objective c or javascript?

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c, ruby

I am trying to run a Ruby script from a cydget (cydget is a framework made by Saurik for writing  lockscreens on the iPhone, using cycript, which is a mix of javascript & objc - see http://www.cycript.org/ ) The script will first check to see if a WEBrick server is running, if so it will quietly exit, if not it will start the server.
Apparently the iPhone doesn't support NSTask, and I don't know if the cycript implementation of obj-c does or not. (To be honest, I have no clue how obj-c in cycript works at all!) I'm not worried about security, because I'm running 1 specific command: "ruby server.rb", and everything else will be handled through the web server itself.

Is there any way other than NSTask in objective-c, or any way in javascript or HTML that I can run an arbitrary command on the local machine?

Thank you!

Brent

Answer (score 0):

You can't fork another process on an iPhone at all (assuming we're talking about a legitimate app developed against Apple's official SDK). No NSTask, no fork()/exec(), no system(), nothing.

Comment: Thanks! This will not be an Apple-sanctioned app. Cydget actually allows you to put webpages from a local directory on the lockscreen, and using cycript in <script type="text/cycript"></script> tags, you can run objective c code. That is definitely not something Apple intentionally allows!
I just don't know what obj c code I need to run to start my server!

Answer (score 0):

So it sounds like the best solution is to just wait - Saurik will be coming out with a way of directly using Ruby in a cydget, but it likely won't be out for a few months...  :(  I hope it will be worth the wait though!